# Враг в юнити идет криво

Tags: unity3d

Я сделал скрипт
Вот этот

```
{
    public Transform player;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        agent.destination = player.position;
        transform.LookAt(player);
    }
}
```

И накинул этот скрипт на врага, а также кинул ему НавМешАгент, однако он идет к игроку боком! я не понимаю почему и не знаю как решить эту проблему, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Значит он у тебя изначально повернут не в ту сторону. Вперед - ось z

Comment: Выложите видео того как он двигается